# Async call of XMLHttpRequest is blocking Jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create Async model where user can upload file using XMLHttpRequest object, in the mean while if user navigates to other functionality containing jquery ajax call then user gets blocked.

I don't want to be user get blocked while uploading file
Please refer following code.

1. Upload file using XMLHttpRequest.

   ```
               var formdata = new FormData();
               formdata.append("keywords", this.element.find('#keywords1').val());
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               // controller call
               xhr.open('POST', '../../Controller/function', true);
               xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
                   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                       if (xhr.status === 200) {

                       } 
                       }
                   }
               }
               xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                   widget._trigger("onProgressStatus", evt, obj);
               }, false);
               xhr.send(formdata);
   ```
2. Jquery ajax call

   ```
           $.ajax({
           type: "POST", 
           url: Controller call,
           headers: headers,
           async: true,
           data: (objConfig.data != undefined) ? objConfig.data : {},
           cache: true,
           contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           timeout: 30000,

           success: function (data) {
             }
           },
           error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           }
       });
   ```

We are using MVC4, Jquery and javascript.

Thanks,
Anish Jain

Comment: What exactly do you want help with?

Comment: Hi, After call file upload using XMLHttpRequest asynchronously if user try to click on other functionality which is containing ajax call (jquery), that jquery ajax need to wait until file upload using XMLHttpRequest gets completed. I want jquery ajax will not depend upon XMLHttpRequest file upload completion. Please Help me :)

Comment: In short, Jquery ajax call should be asynchronous

Comment: The answer is you can't do that in this kind of architecture.
Javascript is not designed with multi-threading feature. That's why in AngularJS, they have concept called Promise. 

If you really want to implement the so called async one, you would need to have iframe to let the uploader handle the uploading file. Just do not use AJAX to upload the files.